# jquery 1.7.2 using template to dynamically update list view

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, jquery-mobile

First of all I am really new to jquery and jquerymobile so sorry if the question is stupid. 
I am trying to port an old project (written in JQ 1.6.4 JQM 1.0b1) to JQ 1.7.2 + JQM 1.1.0. There is a part which uses templates plug-in to dynamically update a list view by parsing a JSON.

Html code:

```html
...
<ul data-role="listview" id="MyItems" data-inset="true"></ul> 
...
```

Template:

```html
<script id="MyListItem" type="text/x-jquery-tmpl">
<li>
    <div class="ui-li-almost-right"><button id="editButton">Edit</button></div>
    <a href="javascript:true" id="connectLink">${symname}&nbsp;</a>
</li>
</script>
```

Updating the list:

```js
$(items).each(function (i, item) {
    var myTemplate=$("#MyListItem").tmpl(item);
    myTemplate.appendTo($("#MyItems"));
});
$("#MyItems").listview("refresh");
```

With a new version if JQ and JQM the list items are generated with class "ui-page" and as a result they are stretched vertically. Can somebody tell me why this is happening and how to avoid it?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You may use the next-gen jQuery Template: JSRender, with:

Template:

```
<script id="MyListItem" type="text/x-jquery-tmpl">
<li>
    <div class="ui-li-almost-right"><button id="editButton">Edit</button></div>
    <a href="javascript:true" id="connectLink">{{:symname}}&nbsp;</a>
</li>
</script>
```

To update the list with data.items:

```
var dataList = $( "#MyList" );
// Create items using template & add to list
dataList.append( $("#MyListItem").render( data.items ) );
// Call listview jQuery UI Widget for correct rendering
dataList.listview( "refresh" );
```

Hope this helps.